# Php: list all @properties of a class

Tags: php, properties

i have a class declared like this:

```
/**
@property string one
@property string two
*/
class X {}
```

I am looking for a way to retrieve a list of (magic) @properties, in this case: [ "one","two" ]

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Comment: Have a look specifically at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php#118606

Comment: Thank you both!
Thanks specially @NigelRen, that it was exactly was i was looking about. 
I got to my goal! Thanks